# Cannot delete file "This action cannot be completed because the file is open in Event Log Watch"

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, file-permissions

I'm trying to delete a file called `lic98.dll` and I fail to do so, I tried cutting the file somewhere else in it works, then I tried deleting and nothing happens, so I'm kinda stuck now on how to delete it.

[image]

Comment: You will have to disable the service connected to the file (which belongs to whichever CA security software you have installed) or uninstall your CA security software in order to delete that file.

Comment: I don't know what could be using and that's the main problem.